# How to simulate a Click() for a button using JavaScript in CefSharp.OffScreen

Tags: javascript, html, c#-4.0, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

I try to make a CefSharp.OffScreen application to simulate a login. But when the website has pop-up screen that opens the log in screen, I cannot click on that login button.

For example, for the html code below it is a sign in button that opens a pop up screen to enter email and password.

```
<spark-button size="medium" full variant="secondary" data-linkname="header-sign-in" data-component="sign-in-start" data-click-intent-id="menu-header-sign-in-link-click" data-activity-rule-type="page-over-page"> 
<button part="base" class="button" type="button" aria-disabled="false" tabindex="0">
        <span part="prefix" class="button__prefix">
          <slot name="prefix"></slot>
        </span>
        <span part="label" class="button__label">
          <slot></slot>
        </span>
        <span part="suffix" class="button__suffix">
          <slot name="suffix"></slot>
        </span>
     </button>
"Sign in" 
</spark-button>
```

I can simulate click on other buttons with `document.getElementsByClassName('nav-user-menu-button')[0].click();` javascript code

But, I cannot do it for that sign in button.

I try `document.getElementsByClassName("spark-button[data-link-name='header-sign-in']")[0].click();` but it gives error as it is does not include click function.

How can I solve the error?

Comment: You can use [CefSharp.Dom](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.Dom#dom-access) to easily emulate mouse clicks.

Answer (score 0):

The button you're attempting to click may be contained within a shadow DOM, which is a distinct DOM tree enclosed within the element, and this may be the cause of the issue you're encountering. In this situation, you won't be able to directly access the button using standard DOM traversal techniques.

TRY :

```js
const signInButton = document.querySelector('spark-button[data-linkname="header-sign-in"]').shadowRoot.querySelector('.button');

signInButton.click();
```

Comment: Yes it has a shadow. But, the example you have provided didn't work as well. If it would help, I gave the example from the website "cars.com" as it consist the pop up window. I can simulate the menu button on that site but cannot do it for the sign in button that open in a pop-up window there.